# Unity player facing wrong way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to unity and have followed a brackeys tutorial to get this. My movement script works, but the player is always facing the wrong direction, and I am unable to change this. I've made an empty gameobject, parented the model to it and put the script into it, but it still won't rotate. [image]

[image: Rotation]

Movement script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class MovementSystem : MonoBehaviour
{

    private CharacterController controller;
    public float positiveZForce = 200f;

    public float negativeZForce = 175f;
    public float xForce = 175f;

    public float yForce = 125f;

    Rigidbody rb;
    public bool isGrounded;

    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground")) {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w")) {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, positiveZForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s")) {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, -negativeZForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a")) {
            rb.AddForce(-xForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d")) {
            rb.AddForce(xForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("space")) {
            if (isGrounded) {
                rb.AddForce(0, yForce, 0);
                isGrounded = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understood this script does not rotate user, it only moves left and right, do you want to rotate the user? Then you should use transform.rotate. There is the example: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Answer (score 0):

The most direct solution would be to call

```
transform.LookAt(transform.position + rb.velocity);
```

in your `FixedUpdate` function. This will cause your `gameObject` to rotate to face in the direction of its motion.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not sure why but your code has rotated my player 180 degrees to be facing the ground.

Comment: This likely because your mesh is not pointing towards the "forward" vector of the root object. By putting your mesh on a child object of the main one, you can compensate for any rotational mismatch and have your mesh point in whichever direction you want "forward" to be defined as.